# Can I apply modifiers to a flip fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

With flip fluids addon, can I take a baked simulation and then modify the mesh as if it were regular geometry?

For example, can I apply a decimate to make a low poly version of the simulation?

Doing this does work in the viewport but then is not applied when rendering. I do have the camera icon activated in the modifier.

EDIT

Apologies, a more specific question:

I have a baked flip fluid simulation mesh. I am experimenting with stylised looks. As a simple test, I want to apply a decimate modifier to the fluid surface mesh to create a low poly mesh.

This does work as expected in the viewport. However the decimate modifier has no effect on the rendered output.

One workaround I have found is to export the sim as an abc and reimport it, then apply whatever modifiers. Is that the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to. I don’t like how this question is raised like you’re wondering whether or not you can do something, but then you change it suddenly to you tried it, and something‘s gone wrong. Right now we have very little info as to why it’s going wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.